# What to do with a this tree which has become too big for its current position?

Tags: trees, tree-removal

I've got an tree ([see this question for ID](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14630/can-this-tree-be-an-eucalyptus-tree-growing-in-central-europe)) which has been planted by the previous owner in a position where it now has outgrown.

I would like to remove it from there and like know what are my options.

Three years ago, when I moved in, the tree was more like a shrub. About 1m high. The first year the winter was quite hard and most of the branches and leaves had died. I thought for good. Then in spring it came back to life. New growth showed up. The last two years the winters were quite mild and thus it grew on and on.

Now it is 3-4 meter high and the main stem is about 8 cm thick at the bottom and it doesn't fit anymore in the place where it is now.

Here are the options I'm currently thinking of and I hope to pick the right one with your help.

1. **Cut - shred - compost it** If this option turns out to be the best one I'd like to know what to with the roots, leave or dig it out?
2. **Cut and cultivate as a shrub** When to cut, how much and what are the risks?
3. **Dig it out and put it into another place** My favorite. What do I need to take care of if this is a possible way? My soil is relatively heavy clay, how will this have influenced root-growth regarding spread and deepness? I surely will harm some roots, how much do I need to cut back the tree in its new position and when to cut back? What is the right position for this tree? Will it work on the south-east-border of a wooden area?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I checked out your other ID question - as a Eucalypt, you can either remove it completely, taking out the roots or killing them with brushwood killer (these develop a long tap root, and by now I'd expect that to be impossible to remove carefully enough to replant elsewhere, specially if its E. gunni), or you can wait till mid spring, then cut it down as low as you like and wait for it to regrow. The possible trouble with that method is, it may not regrow (though its unlikely) - most eucalypts respond well to being cut right down, but a few aren't so pleased with this treatment, though they're usually ones that probably wouldn't make it through European winters anyway. Certainly E. gunni does respond well, and in fact can be grown as a shrub by cutting to the ground every spring, when it will make a shrub about 6 feet high by the end of the growing season. Eucalyptus parvula can be coppiced or pollarded every 5 years or so, or pruned back in spring to keep it smaller.

Comment: I cut it down 2 months ago. No sign of it since then. I'm not unhappy about it, because I can now use the space around it for something else.

Comment: Keep an eye on it in case it shoots after you've replanted around it!